# JavaScript exceptions does not go back from chrome to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I am developing an ASP.NET projekt (ASPX/HTML/JS) with VS2017 + chrome. 
Hitting the breakpoints works with chrome, but JS exceptions does not get back to VS.

Of course I keep the chrome dev window closed. After a JS error, I can open it, and see the exception message.

With IE debugging goes fine.
All the softwares (browsers, VS, Win10) are up to date.

Can I catch JS exceptions in VS2017 from chrome? (or is it only possible with IE?)
Or else what am I doing wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Microsoft is very much a one-stop-shop, and doesn't usually play nice with *any* other software.  I wouldn't be surprised if there was code in VS that _intentionally_ didn't work with non-MS browsers...

Comment: What do you think about this?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the blog you provided in comments, Visual Studio 2017 support Javascript debug. It could let you add breakpoints in your Javascript code and when you debug your application, the breakpoints will be hit.

I also tested the Javascript exception, it only go back when use IE. In Chrome, it will not go back to Visual Studio.

I have submit this issue to Visual Studio Developer Community. You could vote and add comments from below link.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/125436/javascript-exceptions-does-not-go-back-from-chrome.html

Comment: @Jánosi Zoltán János Please select the 'Webkit JavaScript Exceptions' in  'Exception Settings' window. You could see the answer from the feedback link. I have tested and make sure it works in my side.